# In Finder (OS X 10.5.8), is there a way to collapse all folders in list view?

Tags: macos, finder, osx-leopard

I know that cmd-option-left arrow will do this for any one folder, but is there any way to do this for all folders in a given list view?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Press `Cmd-A` to select all, then press `Cmd-Opt-Left` to collapse all.

Comment: Tested on Lion, so it might not work for you.

Comment: Confirmed on 10.6 (actually, isn't  `left` enough?)

Comment: @slhck Subdirectories will only be collapsed with Cmd-Opt-Left.